# Updating number column in SharePoint programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, caml

This is my code which updates single line of text

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = string.Concat("<Where><Eq>",
      "<FieldRef Name=" + txtColumnName.Text + "/>",
      "<Value Type='Choice'>" + txtOldvalue.Text + "</Value>",
      "</Eq></Where>");
query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;

SPListItemCollection it = lst.GetItems(query);
foreach (SPListItem item in it)
{
    item[txtColumnName.Text] = txtNewvalue.Text;
    item.Update();
```

How can I update `number` column and `date-time` column using CAML query?

Answer (score 1):

If you're updating a number column, then set the new value to a number.

```
int number = 10;
item["Column Name"] = number;
item.Update();
```

Likewise if it's a date/time, set the new value to a `DateTime` object.

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 12, 30, 30);
item["Column Name"] = date;
item.Update();
```

Answer (score 1):

`txtNewvalue.Text` seems that your input field is returning `string`.

So all you need is: *Type Casting*.

**String** to **Number**

```
item["InternalNameOfYourNumberColumn"] = decimal.Parse(txtNewvalue.Text);
```

**String** to **DateTime**

```
item["InternalNameOfYourDateTimeColumn"] = DateTime.Parse(txtDateTime.Text);
```

Finally call

```
item.Update();
```

Comment: +1 for the internal column name as "Column Name" won't work.

Comment: No no, it was good before! You need to use internal names when setting values.